# override table name in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have database with three sets of similar tables, about 100M rows of data.

raw_measurements
working_measurements
measurements

raw_measurements contains unadulterated data from csvs from a variety of sensors constantly sending data. once every hour or so, an ETL process is run to clean and add some calculated columns. the final result of that script is put into measurements, which is where data visualization tables are pointed.

Additionally, while the data is being converted, there is a table called working_measurements where the etl scripts actually affect. the final step is to rename working_measurements to measurements, so that there is always a clean copy available for the visualizaion software.

However, in my scripts, I have three models for essentially the same data (this is the problem), one like this:

```
class WorkingMeasurement(Base):
  __tablename__ = "working_measurements"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  box_serial = Column(Integer)
  cycle_id = Column(String(64))
  timestamp = Column(Date)
  wheel = Column(Integer)
  pressure = Column(Float)
  latitude = Column(Float)
  longitude = Column(Float)
  ...
```

and another like this

```
class RawMeasurement(Base):
  __tablename__ = "raw_measurements"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  box_serial = Column(Integer)
  cycle_id = Column(String(64))
  timestamp = Column(Date)
  wheel = Column(Integer)
  pressure = Column(Float)
  latitude = Column(Float)
  longitude = Column(Float)
  ...
```

and yet another like this:

```
class Measurement(Base):

  __tablename__ = "measurements"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  box_serial = Column(Integer)
  cycle_id = Column(String(64))
  timestamp = Column(Date)
  wheel = Column(Integer)
  pressure = Column(Float)
  latitude = Column(Float)
  longitude = Column(Float)
  ...
```

Is there a way to not repeat this information, and only override the **tablename**?

Answer (score 1):

Please read [`Mixin and Custom Base Classes`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html#mixin-and-custom-base-classes) section of documentation. The code below should do the job though:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr

def to_underscore(name):
    import re
    s1 = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s1).lower()


class MeasurementMixin(object):
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return to_underscore(cls.__name__)

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    box_serial = Column(Integer)
    cycle_id = Column(String(64))
    timestamp = Column(Date)
    wheel = Column(Integer)
    pressure = Column(Float)
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longitude = Column(Float)


class WorkingMeasurement(MeasurementMixin, Base):
    pass


class RawMeasurement(MeasurementMixin, Base):
    pass


class Measurement(MeasurementMixin, Base):
    pass
```